# C# sending data to arduino through serial port taking a while

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to send data through the serial port to an arduino and receive data from the arduino. This is my C# code:

```
    private void Fan1Val_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (CONNECTED)
       {
          serialPort1.Write("a" + Convert.ToInt32(Fan1Val.Value) + ";");
       }
    }
```

It controls a PWM fan and this can take up to 30 seconds before the fan speeds up. 
Here is the Arduino code:

```
void loop(){ 
  char data[8] = {};
  if(Serial.available()>0){
        Serial.readBytesUntil(';', data, 8);
  }

  RPM = String(data);
  for(int i=0; i < 12; i++){
    if (RPM.startsWith(designations[i])){
        RPM.remove(0,1);
        analogWrite(pwmChannels[i],RPM.toInt());
    }
  }

  String final;
  String modifier;
  for(int i=0; i < fanPulseLength; i++)
  {
    pulseDuration[i] = pulseIn(fanPulse[i], LOW, 250000);
    frequency[i] = (int)(1000000/pulseDuration[i])/RPMDivider*60;
    if(frequency[i] > 90000){
      modifier = "0";
    }else{
      modifier = String(frequency[i]);
    }
    if(i == fanPulseLength-1){
      final = final + modifier;
    }else{
      final = final + modifier + ";";
    }
  }
 Serial.println(final);
}
```

I also get the RPM from the arduino and this updates at the correct interval. in the C# code. so I know the serial connection is there.

Comment: Try to reduce the println frequency (by sending a println every 100ms, for instance). This will free the buffer. Moreover can you see when the command gets sent? look at the tx led on the board, when it flashes the command is sent. This way you will understand if the problem is on the arduino or in the C# program

Comment: Which Arduino board are you using (UNO, Leonardo, Micro, etc.)?